# Topological Euler characteristic of a cycle of algebraic curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

The topological Euler characteristic of a smooth algebraic curve of genus $g$ equals $2-2g$.

Let $C=\bigcup_{i=1}^n C_i$ be a union of smooth algebraic curves. I am wondering if there is a way to compute the topological Euler characteristic of $C$ in terms of the topological Euler characteristics of $C_i$, $i\in \{1,\cdots,n\}$.

I am assuming that the union is not necessarily disjoint and that the intersections may not be transversal.

Comment: Hint: topological euler characteristic can be computed from cell structures. Can you see how to put a cell structure on $C$ so that you get cell structures on each $C_i$ and their intersections? What do you notice about how the cells are counted?

Comment: Dear @KReiser, I guess that the points of intersection of the curves should be vertices of the cell structure. So it seems that, in order to compute the Euler characteristic of $C$ we should sum the Euler characteristics of the $C_i$'s and subtract $m-1$ every time $m$ curves intersect. If this is right, it looks like having transversal or non transversal intersection do not change the Euler characteristic of $C$.